# Change colour of Okular task-bar-icon in desktop-panel for specific document?

Tags: linux-mint, panel, okular

I use Linux Mint 18 and often have a lot of PDFs open in Okular at the same time. One of these documents is more important than the others, and I want to change the color of its tab, in the panel, so that I can easily see it.

This effect happens on Thunderbird when I get an email as can be seen at the top of the screen shot below (my panel is at the top rather than the bottom of my screen):

[image]

Is there any known way to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to Okular's tab panel? I very much doubt that's possible.

Comment: @DKBose no I'm referring to the panel for the Linux mint desktop. I.e. the thing that contains the button for the linux menu, windows open, time etc and is usually at the bottom of the screen

Comment: So you are talking about the task bar icon?

Comment: @rudib Yep I mean the task bar icon (I think the task bar is called the Panel in linux). But yes the thing with the time, wifi, menu etc as shown at the top of the screen shot above.

Comment: In that case, my answer should work. It will do what thunderbird in your example does. But if you are using Okular's tab feature, it won't work, as all documents would open in the same window. (With this method you can "highlight" a specific window until clicked)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wmctrl` to add the flag `demands_attention`. This will highlight the window icon in the task bar. (It seems that you are looking for a solution like this, as Okular itself does not have tabs. And it's the thunderbird taskbar icon that is highlighted in your example.)

```
wmctrl -a okular -b add,demands_attention
```

As soon you bring focus in the window, it will lose the flag again.

You could write a script that allows you to select the window in the first place and then periodically raise the flag or raise it when triggered.

Here is an example of a bash script that lets you select a window, which will then be marked as `demands_attention`:

```
#!/bin/bash
HANDLE="$(xwininfo | grep 'Window id:' | cut -d ' ' -f4)"
wmctrl -i -a $HANDLE -b add,demands_attention
```

**NOTE:** This will only work if you disable the `Open files in tabs` option in the Okular settings.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. the command `wmctrl -a okular -b add,demands_attention` is just opening the okular window (i.e. showing me the pdf) instead of making the tab red.

Comment: I've tested this on KDE. Maybe cinnamon behaves differently, but it shouldn't really raise the window as well (if it's minimized). But you have to minimize the window before running the command. Let me know if that works, then I'll update the sample script.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way in Okular. (Neither in any other PDF viewer I know off.)

Comment: I think the question is about highlighting the taskbar/tray icon. Okular doen't have tabs for each document AKAIK.

Comment: Okular has tabs as soon as you activate the option in the settings. But maybe you are right about the taskbar higlighting.

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't aware of that. Yes, there is no way to change that besides implementing it. So if OP meant the individual window icons, it's solvable, but not with the Okular-internal tabs.